# After Ubuntu hangs requiring a reboot how to identify the culprit process?

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown, event-log

After having let a new ubuntu 19.0.4 installed machine alone for maybe an hour I found that a direct session from attached keyboard/screen was unresponsive with the screen blank.  In addition  it would take up to a minute to respond in existing  `ssh` sessions to hitting return: and would not actually run any commands.  New `ssh` sessions could not be established  However it *did* respond to `ping`s.  The behavior would seem to be : `599.99% cpu utilization so no soup for you!`.  But I could not get into the system so that can not be verified.

This is an `Alienware R8` with both an integrated and an `nVidia` gpu.  That is mentioned just because the behavior would seem to be a low level `c` or device driver library getting into a tight loop or eating up all memory.  Again this is pure conjecture.

I have looked at the logs using `dmesg` but it seems to have been **reset** after the reboot.

The ask here in the end is - what tools might be useful to isolate the offending software, driver, and/or hardware?

**Update** @EduardoTrapani has an answer forthcoming. I did find this in the `var/log/kern.log`

```
Apr  9 20:04:27 alienware kernel: 
[   10.686707] nvidia: module verification failed: signature 
and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
```

In any case *why* a particular operation failure caused hanging is a completely different topic. That answer leads me to how to find the clues.

Comment: You can see the kernel log in this file `/var/log/kern.log`.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Please make than an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the kernel log in this file /var/log/kern.log (there might be older kernel logs at /var/log/kern.log*, depending on your logrotate policy).

`dmesg` will shows the current content of the kernel's ring buffer, and that only holds a limited amount of messages since boot. The `-F` flag can read from an existing file, for example something like

```
$ sudo dmesg -F /var/log/kern.log
```